# C# How to select two items with the same name in different datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRDlD.png)I have 2 different datagrid, the first DG1 is my item list and DG2 is the item queues for purchased items. My goal is whenever i click an item in DG2, DG1 is also selected with the same name or id. I want to ignore the index because my item queue is different from item list order.

```
private void dgItems_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        int rowindex = dgItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index;
        int columnindex = dgItems.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index;

        dgItemList.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Selected = true;
    }
```

Comment: does you have any code done so far?

Comment: sorry i forgot, just added now, those code can only select the same index, but i need with the same name not just the index.

Comment: you want to select same name row or keep selected previous also?

Comment: Yes, Selected same name row at the same time whenever i click the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access `Value` property from both of datagridviews cell like

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index;
    int columnindex = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        row.Selected = false;

    var cellValue1 = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Value;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        var cellValue2 = row.Cells[columnindex].Value;

        if (cellValue1 == cellValue2)
            row.Selected = true;
        else
            row.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

`dataGridView1` is your  `dgItems` and `dataGridView2` is your `dgItemList`.

**Edit:**

If your both of datagridviews column are on different index then you have to provide column index to match value.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index;
    int columnindex = dataGridView1.Columns[1].Index;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        row.Selected = false;

    var cellValue1 = dataGridView1.Rows[rowindex].Cells[1].Value;  // 1 <= index of Name column in dgItems

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        var cellValue2 = row.Cells[0].Value; // 0 <= index of Name column in dgItemList

        if (cellValue1 == cellValue2)
            row.Selected = true;
        else
            row.Selected = false;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to locate the items by name is to loop through the items in the second list, and return the index of the name that matches your query.

```
private int FindRowIndex(DataGridView view, string searchValue)
{
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in view)
    {
        if(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
            return row.Index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You then simply use this to control which item is being selected in the second table.

```
private void dgItems_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int rowindex = dgItems.Rows[e.RowIndex].Index;
    int columnindex = dgItems.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index;

    dgItemList.Rows[rowindex].Cells[columnindex].Selected = true;

    string searchName = dgItemList.Rows[rowindex].Cells.Value.ToString();
    int secondRowIndex = FindRowIndex(dgItemList2, searchName);

    dgItemList2.Rows[secondRowindex].Cells[columnindex].Selected = true;
}
```

You can repeat the basic loop to locate an alternative column index if needed. Having a method to refer to gives you the ability to repeat the process if you want to click on an item in list 2, and have it select list 1.